# SQL Server 2008 R2 dynamic column name usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table, let's say:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(dummyid numeric(10,0) null,
    on_date datetime      null,
    salary1 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary2 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary3 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary4 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary5 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary6 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary7 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary8 numeric(10,2) null,
    salary9 numeric(10,2) null)
```

I have a procedure that after heavy processing it comes up with a date and a number from 1 to 9.

If 1 is picked for that date I want to return salary1, if 2 is picked I want to return salary2 etc.

I want to avoid using 8 if else clauses:

```
IF @number = 1
    BEGIN
    SELECT @salary = salary1
    FROM test
       WHERE on_date = @on_date

blah 

blah
```

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to get the corect salaryX field depending on the procedure number outcome.

Thanx guys!!

Comment: use a `case` condition rather

Comment: With`SQL Server 2012` you can use `CHOOSE` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019.aspx)

Comment: Naming columns with numbers (like salary1,salary2) is - in almost all cases! - a very clear sign for a bad structure. This cries for a `1:n` related side table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for dynamic code

```
select      case @numebr
                when 1 then salary1   
                when 2 then salary2
                when 3 then salary3
                when 4 then salary4
                when 5 then salary5
                when 6 then salary6
                when 7 then salary7
                when 8 then salary8
                when 9 then salary9
            end                         as salary

from        dbo.test

where       on_date = @date
;
```